# Motivation for hyperbolic metric on upper half plane

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

How to motivate the definition of distance in the upper half plane model of hyperbolic geometry? The book I am using just throws out complicated looking formulas involving ln, with no motivation. I did find a source that provided a detailed derivation for https://mphitchman.com/geometry/section5-3.html for the Poincare disk, which in principle I guess I could translate to the upper half plane, but wondering if there is another explanation?

The metric is $ds^2=\frac{dx^2 + dy^2}{y^2}$ for the Poincare upper half plane model of hyperbolic geometry.

For example for Euclidean geometry on $\mathbb{R}^2$, we can motivate the definition $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2$ via the Pythagorean theorem.

Here is my motivation so far
I'm following in the text "Geometry:A metric approach with models" by Millman and Parker. And so we've so far defined the "lines" in the upper half plane to be the (semi) vertical lines and the semicircles centered on the x-axis. And we've defined "ruler" for a line l as distance preserving bijections $f:l \to \mathbb{R}$. So if we want a bijection from the part of the vertical line say x=2 in the upper-half plane with $\mathbb{R}$, then by considering the inverse function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ we need a bijective strictly function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, and there are many such, but the exponentials form a reasonable.

There is a bijective map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to H$ via $(x, t) \mapsto (x, e^t)$, but the hyperbolic metric pulls back to $$e^{-2t} dx^2 + dy^2$$

But I don't know what to make of that.

Comment: This is a very bad explanation. Why is "exponential" reasonable? The correct explanation goes back to Klein. The Moebius transformations must be isometries.

Comment: I got from a book that the metric $\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}$ and its scalar multiples are the only metrics in $H$ invariant under Moebius transformations mapping $H$ to itself (that is, the ones with real coeficients and determinant $1$).

Comment: @markvs oh yes I agree that it is very unsatisfactory. One could ask well why do we choose only the Mobius transformations be isometries? At that point in the text, complex numbers haven’t been introduced let alone möbius transformations. I suppose the answer maybe the möbius transformation are the automorphisms of H considered as a complex manifold, but the audience I am trying to explain this to hasn’t had complex analysis

Comment: So far  you know only the description of lines?

Comment: Yes we just know just the “lines” in H. The text brings in hyperbolic functions cosh and sinh and since they are involve the exponential, maybe the appearance of exponential function is not too arbitrary. But of course you his reasoning is backwards at best